# How to inject CSS in WebBrowser control?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control

As per my  knowledge,there is a way to inject javascript into the DOM. Below is the sample code that injects javascript with the `webbrowser` control:

```
HtmlElement head = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("head")[0];
HtmlElement scriptEl = webBrowser1.Document.CreateElement("script");
IHTMLScriptElement element = (IHTMLScriptElement)scriptEl.DomElement;
element.text = "function sayHello() { alert('hello') }";
head.AppendChild(scriptEl);
webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("sayHello");
```

Is there an easier way to inject css into the DOM?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I didn't try this myself but since CSS style rules can be included in a document using the `<style>` tag as in:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    h1 {color:red}
    p {color:blue}
</style>
</head>
```

you could try giving:

```
HtmlElement head = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("head")[0];
HtmlElement styleEl = webBrowser1.Document.CreateElement("style");
IHTMLStyleElement element = (IHTMLStyleElement)styleEl.DomElement;
IHTMLStyleSheetElement styleSheet = element.styleSheet;
styleSheet.cssText = @"h1 { color: red }";
head.AppendChild(styleEl);
```

a go. You can find more info on the IHTMLStyleElement [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768673(v=vs.85).aspx).

#### Edit

It seems the answer is much much simpler than I originally thought:

```
  using mshtml;

  IHTMLDocument2 doc = (webBrowser1.Document.DomDocument) as IHTMLDocument2;
  // The first parameter is the url, the second is the index of the added style sheet.
  IHTMLStyleSheet ss = doc.createStyleSheet("", 0);

  // Now that you have the style sheet you have a few options:
  // 1. You can just set the content as text.
  ss.cssText = @"h1 { color: blue; }";
  // 2. You can add/remove style rules.
  int index = ss.addRule("h1", "color: red;");
  ss.removeRule(index);
  // You can even walk over the rules using "ss.rules" and modify them.
```

I wrote a small test project to verify that this works. I arrived at this final result by doing a search on MSDN for IHTMLStyleSheet, upon which I happened across [this page](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ieextensiondevelopment/thread/49dc2c07-ea26-4734-aa2c-99a109ccb46a), [this page](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/f18898b2-9313-4327-a4d9-6104831bfd69/) and [this one](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/iewebdevelopment/thread/33fd33f7-e857-4f6f-978e-fd486eba7174/).

Comment: paracycle, the intellisense of element, doesn't have .text .. thats why im scratching my head right now... :(

Comment: Yes, having another look at the reference document, it seems there is another layer in between. I changes the code snippet to conform to that. I don't have an environment to test the code right now, so please comment on your results.

Comment: there are no IHTMLStyleSheetElement but do have IHTMLStyleSheet and i have tried using IHTMLStyleSheet. It throw NullReferenceException error, styleSheet is not set to an instance of an object. The element's style sheet is null. :(

Comment: I will setup a test environment and update my answer accordingly. It is probably a simple matter of creating a mew HTMLStyleSheet element.

Comment: Thanks paracycle. I find no where to append css in <head> </head>. Looking forward for your answer. :)

Comment: Two things. First: Please mention referenced assemblies and using statements. Otherwise it is hard to use your code. Second: In the first line it has to be `IHTMLDocument2` at the end and not `HTMLDocument2`.

The assembly to add is MSHTML (Microsoft HTML Object Library). And then add `using mshtml;`.

Comment: @RobertS.: I've edited the answer to reflect your comment :)

Comment: @Logos: Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

For me it seemed to be as simple as setting my style first in the `DocumentText.` Obviously not best practices but it works for simple CSS.

```
webBrowser1.DocumentText = "<style> " +
                                 "body { " +
                                    "font-family: Algerian; " +
                                  "} " +
                            "</style> "+
                            "<a href='https://www.google.ca'>Test</a>";
```