# Dynamically creating a new CSS class in a webbrowser document?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, webbrowser-control

Using VB.NET 2010 (Winforms) and targeting .NET 2.0 framework.

On form load, I have a webbrowser control that navigates to a specific URL. Once that URL has been fully loaded by the browser, I click button1 which I want to do the following --> dynamically create a new CSS class named "dashedBorder" in the 'head' section of the loaded webpage DOM. Here's button1's click event code...

```
    Dim Document As HtmlDocument = WebBrowser1.Document
    Dim Head As HtmlElement = Document.GetElementsByTagName("head")(0)

    Dim SelectedStyle As HtmlElement = Document.CreateElement("style")
    SelectedStyle.InnerText = ".dashedBorder {border: 2px dashed yellow !important;}"
    Head.AppendChild(SelectedStyle)
```

When I run the above code, I get a VB error message stating "Property is not supported on this type of HtmlElement".

Any ideas how to create the new CSS class in this scenario? FYI, I do not want to assign that CSS to any particular element at this point -- I simply wish to create the class (in the DOM) so that I can toggle that class on and off with jQuery later on in the code.

Comment: Do some research on how to create a style element in javascript.  That will point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1720320) is a good starting point, but actually it's more simple to make it work in `WebBrowser` control for all IE versions, than described there:

- First, you need to access the native DOM element behind the `SelectedStyle` style object (`NativeSelectedStyle = SelectedStyle.DomElement`);
- Then, `NativeSelectedStyle.type` needs to be set to `"text/css"`;
- At that point, `NativeSelectedStyle.styleSheet` becomes available, otherwise it is `Nothing`;
- Set `NativeSelectedStyle.styleSheet.cssText` to your style sheet content.

Complete example:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted
        Dim Document As HtmlDocument = WebBrowser1.Document
        Dim Head As HtmlElement = Document.GetElementsByTagName("head")(0)

        Dim SelectedStyle As HtmlElement = Document.CreateElement("style")

        Dim NativeSelectedStyle = SelectedStyle.DomElement
        NativeSelectedStyle.type = "text/css"
        ' NativeSelectedStyle.innerHTML = ".dashedBorder { ... }" throws an error
        NativeSelectedStyle.styleSheet.cssText = ".dashedBorder {border: 2px dashed yellow !important;}"

        Head.AppendChild(SelectedStyle)

        MessageBox.Show(SelectedStyle.OuterHtml)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        WebBrowser1.Navigate("about:blank")
    End Sub
End Class
```

**[EDITED]** Now I've found that I essentially copied [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5496632/1768303), so the credit should go to @paracycle. Making this one a wiki.