# Windows Phone - Add CSS to WebBrowser displaying third-party webpage

Tags: css, windows-phone-8, browser, windows-phone

I have an app that displays pages from a website in a **WebBrowser** control. I want to add a **"position:fixed"** to the <header>, either through an inline style or an external stylesheet saved in my app's resources. Is this possible?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5496632/1768303

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, although I'm not sure if for online 3rd party pages as well - from your code you can invoke any JavaScript method using this method:

```
webBrowser.IsScriptEnabled = true; // make sure this property is set on your WebBrowser
webBrowser.InvokeScript(methodName, listOfParameters);
```

you can either have some target JavaScript method in web page code to be invoked, or you can directly invoke any code using the JavaScript "eval" method like this:

```
webBrowser.InvokeScript("eval", new[] { "document.body.style.zoom=\"80%\"" }
```

That's the basic idea, how to change your page programatically from C#, I won't go here into details here how to change CSS values using JavaScript.