# How to get rid of white margin in c# Winform WebBrowser Control?

Tags: c#

I am working on a WinForm (weather app) that use the IE Webbrowser control which displays a weather Map image from Weather Underground.  My problem is that it shows a white margin (or padding) of about 5 px or so, and I can not seem to figure out how to get rid of this white space.(Take a look at image)

I have tried just the Chrome Browser and there is no white space (margin) around the image, however if I try my IE Browser I get the white space(margin).  Is there a setting in IE that sets a Top / Left Margin?

I don't particularly won't to use another webcontrol like Chromium or some other Third party web control, but I will if I have to or either I'll use something a picturebox if I have to.  I was just trying to use the webcontrol.

**Image of IE browser control**
[image: Image of IE browser control]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All browsers have default margins on body but Chrome seems smart enough to not use them when viewing an image instead of HTML. Perhaps inject `body { margin: 0; }` using [How to inject CSS in WebBrowser control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5496549/how-to-inject-css-in-webbrowser-control)

If you load an image in IE and then use F12, it produces:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <img src="file:///C:/Users/Public/Pictures/Sample%20Pictures/Chrysanthemum.jpg">
  </body>
</html>
```

And if you manually add `margin: 0;` to the `body` the border goes away.

Comment: Paul thanks for the heads up on how to inject CSS.  I figured there was a way to control the Web Browser StyleSheet from within C#, however I changed the webBrowser control to a picture box to get rid of the confusion on my part.   Again thanks for the help, I'm sure I'll need more in the future.