# Injecting CSS in WebBrowser Control

Tags: c#, html, css, webbrowser-control

Currently trying to inject CSS in a WebBrowser control using IHTMLStyleSheet

[How to inject CSS in WebBrowser control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5496549/how-to-inject-css-in-webbrowser-control)

I read this and I think it helped a bit but what's there doesn't seem to work for me.

```
        IHTMLDocument2 doc = (webBrowser1.Document.DomDocument) as IHTMLDocument2;
        IHTMLStyleSheet ss = doc.createStyleSheet("", 0);                        
        ss.addRule("body", "background-color:#000");
        ss.cssText = @"h1 { color: blue; }";
```

This is what I currently have, do I need to add it to the control after this or what am I doing wrong here?

EDIT:
Got it working here's what I did

```
            CurrentDocument = (mshtml.HTMLDocument)webBrowser1.Document.DomDocument;
            styleSheet = CurrentDocument.createStyleSheet("", 0);

            StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(@"test.css"); //test.css is Stylesheet file
            string text = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            streamReader.Close();
            styleSheet.cssText = text;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I did to get it working

```
        CurrentDocument = (mshtml.HTMLDocument)webBrowser1.Document.DomDocument;
        styleSheet = CurrentDocument.createStyleSheet("", 0);

        StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(@"test.css"); //test.css is Stylesheet file
        string text = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        streamReader.Close();
        styleSheet.cssText = text;
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel like you are trying to do this the hard-way.

Why not use the built-in winforms way of doing this instead of COM-Interop?

The easiest way would be to simply load your css file into memory and append it's string to the Style element of the web browser document. Or if you just want to change one particular element use the Style property

**C#**

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace stackoverflow
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.google.com");
            webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted;
        }
        private void WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            var FeelingLucky= webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("gbqfbb");
            FeelingLucky.Style = "font-size: 40px;";

            var path = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.Environment.CurrentDirectory, "Stylesheet1.css");
            var StylesheetContent = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path);
            var style= webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("style")[0];
            style.InnerText = style.InnerText + " " + StylesheetContent;
        }
    }
}
```

**CSS file**

```
#lga {background-color: red;}
```

**Here is google after the modifications above:**
[image: Google]

Take a look at the MSDN documentation on [Style](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement.style(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Robin , great job buddy. You know you can add your own answer to the question and then accept it in 2 days?